# Different form of using Class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QVersionNumber Class in Qt project. and tried 2 solutions, one is working and another not.

What is the difference between A and B?

in A I'm writing like this:

```
QVersionNumber imageVersion = QVersionNumber::fromString(payloadRegex_image.cap(3));
QString imageVersionString(imageVersion.toString());
```

and in B I'm writing like this:

```
QVersionNumber imageVersion;
 imageVersion.fromString(payloadRegex_image.cap(3))
QString imageVersionString(imageVersion.toString());
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qversionnumber.html#fromString).  `fromString` is a static member function so `imageVersion.fromString(...` in the second code snippet will *not* modify `imageVersion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [fromString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qversionnumber.html#fromString) is static public member function that does not access `this` object at all. So in second snippet you ignore its return value and it does nothing.